# Entity Framework AsNoTracking Not Working In GroupJoin

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, outer-join

I have the following model

```
public class Rate
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // PK
    public int SpecialId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "Money")]
    public decimal Rental { get; set; }
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

And the following...

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // PK
    public int SpecialId { get; set; }

    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

I am joining the two on SpecialId using a GroupJoin using the following query.

```
var query = _context.Vehicle.AsNoTracking()
        .GroupJoin(_context.Rate.AsNoTracking(),
        vehicle => vehicle.SpecialId,
        rate => rate.SpecialId,
        (v, r) => new VehicleQuery
        {
            Rates = r, 
            Vehicle = v
        }).AsNoTracking();
```

... and returning a VehicleQuery model (Show below)

```
public class VehicleQuery
{
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Rate> Rates { get; set; }
}
```

However, even though I have AsNoTracking on the Rate table and the final query, when I look at the results in the debugger.

I can see that the Rates are still tracked (DynamicProxies). However the Vehicle is fine and showing as normal class and not a dynamic proxy/tracked.

I have even tried r.ToList() in the VehicleQuery but it's still showing as a DynamicProxie?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: try setting ProxyCreationEnabled as false & then run the query.

Comment: @TechieBee I can't turn it off as I am doing other queries on other tables where I need tracking. The context is per request, so if I turn it off then it will be off for all the other queries.

Comment: Set only for this query.

Comment: @TechieBee but you set it on the context, and that context is used for other queries in the same request?

Comment: Oh..Same request!! then not possible.As far as i knw, thats the only option but you cannot do it partially(set only for certain tables)

Comment: I don't understand why it's not possible when I have explicitly added AsNoTracking() which works fine normally.

Comment: The reason is : If you define your navigation property virtual , EF will at runtime create a new class (dynamic proxy) derived from your Rate class and use it instead. This new dynamically created class contains logic to load navigation property when accessed for the first time.